# O365 MS Graph Unified API token lifetime

Tags: odata, office365, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

I have two questions about token usage and their expiry:

1) about user's secret code for application

I need secret code to authenticate. When creating secret code in application it can be defined with expiration one or two years. My goal is application which user installs, sets up, and it can be 'forgotten'. But this expiration could mean that application will start failing after one year, is that correct? User will start to get token errors and he will have to re-setup the application again (generate new secret key and authenticate with it). Can I find out expiration from secret key, so I could set up a notification for user BEFORE it gets expired? I'd like to do that to avoid application stop working just suddenly.

2) client authentication is done in two steps:

- one: app client id + client secret key + source + user authentication = code
- two: app client id + client secret key + code = token + refresh token

I found that if I do step one and I want to perform step two later then 'code' from step one may be expired. I thought that 'code' does not expire, but I can't find any documentation about that. **Is that correct, that step two should be done right after step one?**

Comment: Is this for an application that will run on a user's device (computer, phone, etc.)?

Comment: No, it should be for a application that will run as service/azure. Maybe I should use this approach instead: "Service to Service Calls Using Client Credentials" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645543.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1) If that is a web service, you could use OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials Grant Flow . In consideration of security , I would suggest you could maintain/update the secret key periodically , the duration of the secret key could be one year or two years . If the secret key is compromised, a new one must be generated and all authorized apps will have to be updated with the new client secret.

2) You could click [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645545.aspx) for details about how to use OAuth 2.0 to authenticate. In Service-to-Service access token response, you will get the expires_in(How long the access token is valid) and expires_on(The time when the access token expires) information . You should write your code to anticipate the possibility that a granted token might no longer work and request a new one .